# Several shape keys blocking mesh face trasformation?

Tags: shape-keys

I newly started using shape keys to create an animation, which is just a cube wobbling on the spot, the first shape key that I applied was the top face of the cube rotating slightly, and to this point it went all good. Then I wanted to add another shape key, making the same face rotate back to place. When I created the Shape key, I went to Edit mode, but when I tried to rotate the face, it wouldn't move at all. I could see the dotted arrow as I usually would when rotating, while the face remained still.I tried using the hot keys (R -> Z), the Mesh tools -> transform, and 3D widget manipulator and all of them resulted in the same. I tried to do the same thing to the first Shape key and it worked, while the second did not, even though both seemed to have the exact same settings
 [image: the result of pressing R -> Z. The dotted line coming from the faces origin point would follow the cursor, but the face would not move]

Answer (score 2):

You probably enabled the option which allows you to see the applied shapekey in Edit Mode. 
[image]

Please set the shapekey value up to 1, and then edit the mesh or just disable this option.
[image]

Comment: Ok so i put the value to 1.000 so I could edit the mesh and set the standard for the shape key. The thing is, when I move the value to 1, the shape simply shrinks all the way, dissapearing completely at value 1.000, making it impossible to transform. Is there any way to "reset" the shape key in any way?

Comment: here are some pics: [link](http://i.imgur.com/jTzY1NG.jpg)

Comment: Could you post your .blend file via pasteall.org. It would be easier to help you then.

Comment: ok I uploaded the file as "Spinning jello". I hope I did everything right since i have never used PasteAll.

Comment: Please post the link to your pasteall file.

Comment: There seems to be an error uploading the file... even though it worked last time.

Comment: Ok here it is: [link]http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34999

Comment: Sorry for not responding for a long time. I saw the file and you should probably delete the not working shapekey using '-' symbol in shapekeys panel and try to add a new one and edit it properly once again.

Comment: Ok awesome, thanks for your time and patience!

Comment: @Olibrot if this does answer your question please mark it as accepted